# Strange markings on i7 5820 Haswell CPU

Tags: cpu

Purchased a new i7 5820K from Amazon. I found these markings on the cpu; is this normal for Haswells? I thought maybe it's caused by quality assurance and/or testing from Intel's manufacturing process.

There's no sign of thermal paste, none at all, so I don't believe it's used, but I could be wrong.

[image]

Comment: It came in a properly sealed box?

Comment: Yes, though it appears to be [normal](http://www.overclock.net/t/1550568/brand-new-i7-5820k-from-amazon-looks-used-or-refurbished-what-the-hell/10) manufacturing byproduct, according to folks at overclock.net